# Infragistics Drag and Drop Tree Expand Multiple Nodes Simultaneously

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc, infragistics

I am using the following Infragistics component for viewing hierarchical data.
http://www.igniteui.com/tree/drag-and-drop-single-tree

I could able to load data correct but the problem is wI cant expand multiple nodes simultaneously. I mean when I expand a node the other node collapsed expanding only the current node. Can some one please suggest if there is any configuration setting I am missing to accomplish this?

I want the nodes once expanded will remain expanded until user collapses it again.

Thanks,
Krishna Prasad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The option that controls that is `singleBranchExpand`. Set it to `false` to allow multiple nodes to be expanded at the same time. http://jsfiddle.net/ywtLL7ka/

```
$("#tree").igTree({
    singleBranchExpand: false,
});
```